# Numba : "This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function"

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

When calling a class method on an object using Numba's @jitclass decorator, it would appear that 
the "self" argument is not supported. Not sure what to make of the errors here.
Everything compiles just fine but the individual methods are not jiving, despite other numpy functions being called.

```
spec = [('raster',numba.float32[:,:]),('height', numba.int32),('width', numba.int32),('azis', numba.int64[:]),('grid',numba.int64),('rough',numba.float64[:,:]),('maxrange',numba.float64[:,:]),('aziratio',numba.float64[:,:]),('labels',numba.float64[:,:])]

@jitclass(spec)
class raster_class(object):
    def __init__(self,raster):
        self.raster = raster
        self.height =self.raster.shape[0]
        self.width = self.raster.shape[1]
        self.azis =  np.arange(0,170,10)
        self.grid = 500
        x = np.int(self.height/self.grid)
        y = np.int(self.width/self.grid)
        self.rough = np.zeros((x,y))
        self.maxrange = np.zeros((x,y)) 
        self.aziratio = np.zeros((x,y))
        self.labels = np.zeros((x,y))


    def detrend(self):
        raster -= ndimage.gaussian_filter(self.raster,sigma=40)
        return raster


    def SR(self,image):
        image = image[~np.isnan(image)] # remove nan's
        image = np.ndarray.flatten(image)
        mean = np.mean(image)

        return np.sqrt((1/(len(image)-1))*np.sum((image-mean)**2))
    def getRange(self,mat):
    # fits an anisotropic variogram model and returns the effective range for a given azimuth
        m,n = mat.shape
        vals = np.reshape(mat,(m*n,1))
        coords = []
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                coords.append((i,j))
                coords = np.array(coords)
                response = np.hstack((coords,vals))
                response = response[~np.isnan(response[:,-1])]
                response = response[response[:,-1] != 0]
                response = response[~np.isnan(response[:,-1])]
                coords = response[:,:2]
                response = response[:,2]
                response += np.random.normal(0,scale=0.25,size=response.shape[0]) #add noise to prevent same values

         azi_r = []
         for azi in self.azis:
            DV =  DirectionalVariogram(coords,response,azimuth=azi,tolerance=15,maxlag=250,n_lags=20) 
            azi_r.append(DV.cof[0])

        major = np.argmax(azi_r)
        large_range = azi_r[major]
        major = azis[major]

        if major  >= 90:
            perp = major - 90
        else:
            perp = major + 90
        minor = azis.index(perp)
        minor_range = azi_r(minor)
        ratio = large_range/minor_range
        return ratio,large_range

    def iterate(self):
        for i in range(0,self.height-self.grid,self.grid):
            for j in range(0,self.width-self.grid,self.grid):
                image = self.raster[i:i+self.grid,j:j+self.grid]
                indi = int(i/self.grid)
                indj = int(j/self.grid)
                roughness = self.SR(image)
                ratio,range_ = self.getRange(image)
                self.azi_ratio[indi,indj] = ratio
                self.largest_range[indi,indj] = range_
                self.response_rough[indi,indj] = roughness

if __name__ == "__main__":
    brooks = np.load("brooks_dem.npy")
    brooks_class = raster_class(brooks)
    time = time.time()
    brooks_class.iterate()
    end_time = time.time() - time
    hours = end_time/3600
    print("Computation Took {} Hours".format(hours))
```

**Error Message**

```
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the 
named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at /home/dunbar/DEM/processraster.py (35)

File "processraster.py", line 35:
    def SR(self,image):
        image = image[~np.isnan(image)] # remove nan's
        ^

[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 
'numba.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'SR') for 
instance.jitclass.raster_class#55ac81be91b8<raster:array(float32, 2d, 
A),height:int32,width:int32,azis:array(int64, 1d, A),grid:int64,rough:array(float64, 2d, 
A),maxrange:array(float64, 2d, A),aziratio:array(float64, 2d, A),labels:array(float64, 2d, 
A)>)
[2] During: typing of call at /home/dunbar/DEM/processraster.py (81)


File "processrabster.py", line 81:
    def iterate(self):
        <source elided>
                indj = int(j/self.grid)
                roughness = self.SR(image)
                ^

[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 
'numba.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'iterate') for 
instance.jitclass.raster_class#55ac81be91b8<raster:array(float32, 2d, 
A),height:int32,width:int32,azis:array(int64, 1d, A),grid:int64,rough:array(float64, 2d, 
A),maxrange:array(float64, 2d, A),aziratio:array(float64, 2d, A),labels:array(float64, 2d, 
A)>)
[2] During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Comment: This is clearly not the entire error message, because it's telling you where the error is and a guess as to why, but not *what*. Also, please fix the indentation of your posted code.

Comment: Anyway, is the code working *without* the decorator? Also, are you able to produce a shorter example that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: It looks like `SR` is a staticmethod, which may have some bearing on this. It is notable that @jitclass is an [experimental feature](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html) and has actually been moved to numba.experimental in the latest release. When it comes to numba I think it is preferable to use pure functions (use @njit) then use regular python classes as glue if necessary.

Comment: As we discovered with the `__Init__`, `numba` is picky about defining variables.  I don't see anything that tells `numba` about `image`.  Don't expect `numba` to be as flexible as python/numpy.  I suspect you are going at this whole `numba` use the wrong way.  Identify simple functions that take extra time, especially ones that are iterative and can make good use of compiled numpy methods.  Focus on using `numba` on those.  Don't try to use `numba` for the whole code or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the `SR` method, though unfortunately the jitclass error message is not very informative beyond that. Since this is a static method, though, a very easy way to debug it is to test it as a standalone function, i.e. to take `SR` out of the class, remove the `self` argument, add an `@njit` decorator, and run `SR` on an arbitrary two-dimensional array.

When I do this, I find the following two problems:

1. `image[~np.isnan(image)]` is a form of "fancy" or "advanced" indexing, since it uses a boolean array as input. Numba [only supports advanced indexing on a single dimension](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#array-access), but `image` is two-dimensional.
2. You're calling `flatten` like a function from its `ndarray` class, i.e. `np.ndarray.flatten(image)`, but Numba only recognizes the more standard method call `image.flatten()`.

You could fix point #1 by switching the order of the two lines, writing `image = image.flatten()` first (or `image = image.ravel()`, since there is no need to make a copy), and then `image = image[~np.isnan(image)]` second.

Fortunately, for your particular application there's **no need to do any of this**, since it seems like the `SR` method can be replaced with a call to [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), which is supported by Numba.

More generally, I endorse the comments suggesting that compiling a large class like this with Numba is not really the intended use (at least for now); better to identify some bottlenecks with profiling and compile those specifically.